# Pdfwriter: document has no content

Tags: java, pdf

I'm creating an automatic reminder system for a company and have encountered some problems while rewriting my code (Note: the code has worked - but essential, big changes have been made). Hours of puzzling and looking at the changes that I've made, have not solved this. It creates the pdf succesfully, the metadata is correctly added and the method addLine is added correctly as well.

I've uploaded my code (Note: some private information has been removed).
The code obviously consists of plenty of variables, but I can almost assure that the data variables (like street, company, postal code, amount paid, etc.) are no issue.
No exception has been caught, no error has been thrown.

https://pastebin.com/zNJFHuyt for the whole code (have to add code so I just drop some lines :D)

```
 Document document = new Document();
        String Filepath;

        if(companynumber==0)
            Filepath = "C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/pyxus/opslagaanmaningen/pyxis/" + debiteur + " " + datenow + ".pdf";
        else
            Filepath = "C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/pyxus/opslagaanmaningen/zwaluw/" + debiteur + " " + datenow + ".pdf";

        PdfWriter Writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Filepath));
        document.open();
        addMetaData(document);
        addTitlePage(document, debiteur, bedrijf, termijn, counts, companynumber);
        addline(Writer, counts);
        document.close();
```

Comment: Additional information: replacing the content to just "hallo" doesnt add it either! So it indicates that there's a problem with the way I'm trying to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `createTable` method contains these lines:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String invoice = list.get(i);
```

This automatically throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

This code is contained in a loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < Reader.getInvoicesList(debiteur).size(); i++)
```

So the exception can only be evaded if `Reader.getInvoicesList(debiteur).size()` is 0 or less. As you don't observe an exception, this must be the case for your data.

This in turn means, though, that the table created in `createTable` is never added to the document as it is only added to the document at the end of that loop.

Thus, the only content added to the PDF are the lines drawn by

```
addline(Writer, counts);
```

---

You should clean up the `createTable` method, there are numerous issues in it in addition to those mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I'd solved it already haha. I fixed it by just rewriting it againXD

Comment: Well, as mentioned above, there were numerous issues in `createTable` and the whole architecture, so the re-write was appropriate.